how to run terraform graph command on a given plan
I need to debug a cyclic dependency on one environment. All the others work with the same plan/.tf-files. The reason for this could be that on the problematic environment some resources are not yet destroyed. These environments are defined via .tfvar files and usually passed to plan and apply like this:
terraform plan -var-file="./envs/some-env/terraform.tfvars"

It is suggested to use the terraform graph command to view the cause of the cyclic dependency.
The terraform graph command has 4 options
Options:

  -plan=tfplan     Render graph using the specified plan file instead of the
                   configuration in the current directory. Implies -type=apply.

  -draw-cycles     Highlight any cycles in the graph with colored edges.
                   This helps when diagnosing cycle errors. This option is
                   supported only when illustrating a real evaluation graph,
                   selected using the -type=TYPE option.

  -type=TYPE       Type of operation graph to output. Can be: plan,
                   plan-refresh-only, plan-destroy, or apply. By default
                   Terraform just summarizes the relationships between the
                   resources in your configuration, without any particular
                   operation in mind. Full operation graphs are more detailed
                   but therefore often harder to read.

  -module-depth=n  (deprecated) In prior versions of Terraform, specified the
                   depth of modules to show in the output.

The following 2 work but do not indicate any cyclic errors in red, likely because it is not run against the only failing env.
terraform graph -draw-cycles 
terraform graph -draw-cycles -type=plan > graph.dot

So I tried to run it on an created plan. To do this the type has to be set to apply when following the help text. However this errors out with.
terraform graph -draw-cycles -type=apply -plan=plan.out > graph.dot
Too many command line arguments. Did you mean to use -chdir?

So my Question is how to correctly run the terraform graph on a specific plan?
I'm using version 1.7.5 and 1.9.6 of terraform on windows which both show the same behavior

Just to clarify - does the cyclic dependency already show up when doing terraform plan with the variables set to the problematic environment? Or does it only show up when doing terraform apply?

@V.Prins it shows up in plan, that's why I did not run apply yet (this is all usually run via CI/CD and therefore the apply can't be run if plan step is red). Currently I'm trying to debug this locally in "read only mode" to see how i can fix this.

What does terraform graph -draw-cycles -plan=plan.out > graph.dot do for you? Where plan.out is the plan file of the failing plan?

@V.Prins it fails with Too many command line arguments. ... the issue was that the filename needs to be enclosed with " in powershell - pretty stupid mistake I made.
however the output still shows nothing red

It came down to me not properly escaping the commands for powershell. The difference to the above commands is " around the paths for plan.out
The correct way to run terraform graph is as follows:
terraform plan -var-file="./envs/some-env/terraform.tfvars" -out="plan.out" -var image_tag=test123
terraform graph -draw-cycles -type="apply" -plan="plan.out" > graph.dot

The created output can then be passed to an online Service like https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/ to be interpreted as SVG
